# Has anyone brewed Keptinis beer?

Tags: recipe

I would like to try my hand at brewing Keptinis (I've read [Lar's blog](http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/394.html)). I would like a recipe geared towards modern homebrewers and I'm most interested in the baking part and how to do that in a standard oven or grill. I think the rest I can figure out with my setup. Thanks!

Comment: The article you linked to says 50kg pale malt for 130 liters of beer, so for a 20 liter (5 gallon) batch I'd go with 1/6 of that, i.e., 8kg (17.5 lbs) of malt. I'd bake it in regular oven dishes like for lasagna. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Looking for someone that has experience making this type of beer on a modern homebrew setup. The baking part too, which seems to be the hardest part...

Comment: I dont think a modern oven can reach 350c/660f....but if you set your oven to clean, mines tops out at 500f, then let the mash bake till its finished and then let it cool down.

Comment: I'm not sure it's absolutely necessary to get to that temperature, but I have a big gas grill that will. I plan on trying a version of this when it cools off a bit...

Comment: @farmersteve looking at that blog you spoke of there appear to be some people in the comment section who seem to be successful with that recipe, have you found out anything more?

Comment: @765tgs Thanks for mentioning that I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

Recipe that I came up with that I will be brewing after my current one.

100% 2 row pale malt

34 IBUs using noble hops, bittering only

SG 1.060

FG unknown, due to caramelization of sugars during baking.

Yeast - any neutrel yeast, but a Saison yeast would be interesting.

Procedure

1. Mash, medium to light body
2. Bake in large baking dishes with high lip, sorta like lasagna dish. 450F till dark brown my guess is 3 hours, let cool in oven.
3. Sparge baked mash till desired  volume and gravity
4. make Hop Tea, then add to FV

> Take 120g bitter hops (14% alpha acid) and 50g aroma hops (5-6% alpha) and boil them for 30 minutes in 2 liters of water. There was no very clear aroma of hops in the beer, so some noble hop will probably work best. 
>   Blockquote

I would scale this down and use 1L of tea, and calculate for 34 IBUs

5. Ferment as normal.

I will update this in a few weeks when I finalize the process.

FYI this is a no boil beer.

Comment: Would be very keen to know how your brew turns out.

Comment: Putting the mash in the oven at 450 for 3 hours would cause the mash to boil, right?

Comment: yes, it would cause some of the water to boil.